# Understanding memory management in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've got the following code that works OK, but I'm not sure if I understood correctly some memory management concepts:

```
#import "mapPoint.h"

@implementation mapPoint
@synthesize coordinate, title, subtitle;

-(id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c title:(NSString *)t {
    [super init];
    coordinate = c;
    [self setTitle:t];
    // Set date as subtitle
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *myDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    [self setSubtitle:myDate];
    [dateFormatter release];
    // Look for city and state; when found, set it in subtitle, replacing date
    geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:c];
    [geocoder setDelegate:self];
    [geocoder start];
    return self;
}
-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
-(void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark {
    [self setSubtitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"City: %@, State: %@", [placemark locality], [placemark administrativeArea]]];
}
-(void)dealloc {
    [title release];
    [subtitle release];
    [geocoder release];
    [super dealloc]; 
}

@end
```

1. As I created the geocoder object via the `alloc` method, I have to release it (done in `dealloc`). Correct?
2. In method `reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark` a NSString is created with the convenience method `stringWithFormat`. As I didn't use `alloc`, I'm not responsible for releasing that (I assume that method uses `autorelease`). Is that right?
3. The object `placemark` returns two NSStrings, `locality` and `administrativeArea`. Again, I didn't create those strings, so I'm not releasing them. However, given that they are part of the subtitle property of my mapPoint object, I don't want those strings to disappear, but they probably were created with `autorelease`. The property `subtitle` is declared with `retain`. Is is correct to assume that it will retain the NSString created with the convenience method, preventing it's premature destruction?

Thanks, and apologies if the questions are complicated... the subject is.

Comment: AFAIK, Yes, you are correct in your justifications :)

Comment: I second Mahesh's comment. :)

Comment: Objective-C has no memory management. It's the **frameworks** and **libraries** you use with it. In other words: the title of this question, and the tags, are wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. geocoder is an ivar in your class? Then your code is correct. Note that, since the geocoder is useless after it returns a result, you *could* release it (and set the ivar to nil) in the appropriate delegate methods to allow the memory to be reclaimed earlier.
2. Correct, mostly. If you had used a method starting with "new" or containing "copy" to get the instance of the object, you would also be responsible for releasing it.
3. Correct on all points. Note that if you were to implement `setSubtitle:` yourself instead of allowing `@synthesize` to do it, you would be responsible for implementing that behavior in your implementation of `setSubtitle:`.

---

**Edit:**

I see in comments that you are particularly concerned about point 3. The strings from `[placemark locality]` and `[placemark administrativeArea]` are passed as parameters to NSString's `stringWithFormat` method, after which they are irrelevant because their content has been copied into the new string that `stringWithFormat` returns. That is the only string you really have to worry about, and as has been pointed out `setSubtitle:` will retain that string.

Comment: 1. @Anomie: Thanks :) Yes, it's an ivar. Great idea about releasing it in the delegate method (I should not release it anymore in the `dealloc` method, right?). What's the difference in terms of freeing memory between releasing geocoder and setting geocoder to nil?

Comment: You should still release it in the `dealloc` method, just in case the delegate methods for some reason never got called. That is why I said "(and set the ivar to nil)", as `[nil release]` does nothing.

Comment: In this case, "releasing geocoder" and "setting geocoder to nil" are two different things. The first is necessary to prevent memory leaks, while the second is just housekeeping to make sure that you cannot accidentally try to use geocoder again after you have released it. This should not be confused with setting a *property* declared "retain" to nil, as that both releases the old value and does the housekeeping (some prefer to do this while some prefer explicitly releasing the ivar and setting it nil).

Answer (score 1):

Much has been written and said -- here and elsewhere -- about Cocoa memory management. Fundamentally, it's all an attempt to paraphrase or explain this: [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). Accept no substitutes. :-)

Comment: It seems to me that ryback has read that document and is asking this question to confirm that he/she correctly understands everything.

Comment: There's no evidence one way or the other in the question. And so many helpful people get the answers *wrong* that it seems important to make sure that they know where the authoritative answers lie.

Comment: Effectively, I read the Memory Management Rules document, but I find it complicated to follow the rules in point 3, where two strings are used to build a new one, that is ultimately assigned to a property. I'm not sure how many of these objects get retained. My interest is that the property `subtitle` does not end up referencing to a deallocated string.

Comment: Anomie's edit is exactly on target: what happens with the properties of `placemark` is entirely irrelevant to you. You look at those strings, copy them into your subtitle (which is retained because it's a property accessor that says so), and what happens after that doesn't matter. If you wanted to keep those values yourself, you'd need to take ownership (copy or retain).

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you need to release geocoder in dealloc
2. Yes, you are not responsible for releasing the NSString
3. Yes, you are not responsible for releasing those NSStrings.

To obtain a better understanding of the memory management rules and standards, I would suggest reading the '[Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)' In particular, you may want to take some extra time to read the section 'Object Ownership and Disposal'.

Comment: Thanks. I read some portions of the document, although I can't completely understand it. My particular concern is point 3: geocoder object creates MKPlacement object, that contains two strings. These two strings then derive in a new string, that is assigned to the `subtitle` property. I don't want `subtitle` to point to a deallocated memory region, as well as I don't want to innecessarily retain intermediate strings.

Comment: @ryback Calling setSubtitle (because subtitle is a retained property) will cause the string to be retained. It will not point to deallocated memory. stringWithFormat creates an autoreleased string, but that release will not occur until after the retain in setSubtitle.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already addressed your main questions, but I'd like to point out a few other things:

- It is conventional to assign the result of `[super init]` to `self`, like this:

  ```
  - init
  {
      self = [super init];
      if (!self) return nil;

      // do initialisation

      return self;
  }
  ```

  There are other, similar constructs that revolve around the value returned by `[super init]`, but they always (by convention) involve assigning to `self` first.
- Although unlikely to cause any problems in this case, it is generally more acceptable to avoid using accessor methods like `setTitle:` and `setSubtitle:` inside an initialiser method. The reason being that you may inadvertently trigger KVO notifications when your object is only in a partially-initialised state.

Comment: What is going to be observing keys on the object when it hasn't been initialized yet?

Comment: @Anomie: Anything where you provide `self` as an argument to other initialisers, or setting delegates etc. Like I said, in this particular case there shouldn't be any problems.

Comment: if I understand well, you are suggesting that I replace `[super init]` with `self = [super init]`?  // Re your 2nd point, what alternatives do I have for `setTitle:` and `setSubtitle:`? Directly assigning the value to the instance variable without using the accessor method?

Comment: @ryback: Yes, you are correct in both cases. The second one is more of an "FYI". Some people *prefer* to use accessor methods in initialisers simply because it keeps memory management in one place, while others (including Apple) prefer to assign directly to instance variables, usually just to give the object a better chance at being fully initialised before its first use.